# using sharepoint user credentials in a flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, flex4

I am deploying a flex application in sharepoint as a web part.
I am planning to use sharepoint user credentials for my flex application.
My flex application consists of various different user roles like author,reviewer etc .
An author should be able to see all the list of sharepoint users available and can make any number of them as reviewer or author . For this I require following functionality through sharepoint for my flex application:-

1) Getting list of all users of sharepoint

2) Getting the username of the current logged in user of sharepoint through the flex application, which is deployed as a web part in sharepoint.

How to do this ?

Comment: How about passing the logged on user name as InitParam? You can write a webpart that generate the object tag with required initparam. Logged on user name info is available to server side / webpart code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this by creating a custom asp.net web service and deploying it on sharepoint.Through this web service , I retrieved current user and the list of users using share point object model.Flex inquires this web service for current user and list of available users